# setting up ajax validation response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My PHP code for a login form [this part located at the very top on my index.php where I have the login form] looks something like this:

```html
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 if (!isset($_POST['username'])) $error[] = "Please fill out all fields";
 if (!isset($_POST['password'])) $error[] = "Please fill out all fields";

 $username = $_POST['username'];
 if ( $user->isValidUsername($username)){
  if (!isset($_POST['password'])){
   $error[] = 'A password must be entered';
  }
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  if($user->login($username,$password)){
   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
   header('Location: welcome.php');
   exit;

  } else {
  $error[] = '<div style = "text-align:center">Wrong username/password or your account have not been activated </span>';
  }
 }else{
  $error[] = '<div style = "text-align:center">Username required</span>';
 }
```

and the HTML for the login form is like this:

```html
  <form role="form" method="post" action="" >

    <?php
    //check for any errors
    if(isset($error)){
     foreach($error as $error){
      echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</p>';
     }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['action'])){

     //check the action
     switch ($_GET['action']) {
      case 'active':
       echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Your account is now active you may now log in.</h2>";
       break;
      case 'reset':
       echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Please check your inbox for a reset link.</h2>";
       break;
      case 'resetAccount':
       echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Password changed, you may now login.</h2>";
       break;
     }

    }

    
    ?>

    <div class="form-group">
     <p align="center">
     <font face="Tahoma">Username:</font><font color="#FFFFFF">
     </font>
     <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-lg"  value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES); } ?>" tabindex="1">
     </div>
<br>
    <div class="form-group">
     <p align="center">
     <font face="Tahoma">Password: </font><font color="#FFFFFF">
     &nbsp;</font><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg"  tabindex="3">
    </div>
                             <br>
    <div align="center">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn1" tabindex="5">
    </div>
                             
    

                             
                        </form>
```

Now, as this form in submitted if there are ERRORS , it will refresh the whole page and back with error messages on right on top of the form fields. How would I be able to use AJAX / jQuery response to validate for ERRORS without refreshing the whole page. ONLY of there are ERRORS I want it pop the error messages without refreshing. And if it's SUCCESS, then it would log the user in. Can someone help me with this ?

I also have a errors.php file that has only this code in it:

```html
<?php  if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>
  <div class="error">
   <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
     <p><?php echo $error ?></p>
   <?php endforeach ?>
  </div>
<?php  endif ?>
```

I get the concept behind setting up the AJAX method, but IDK how to use it on this code and form. Hope you guys can help.

Comment: I think it is better to use a different action page for checking the login credential and initializing the session variable instead of using the same page.. Then it will be easier for you . Just send the form's data via AJAX and in the action page, just assign the session value (No redirect) and echo 1 if success else echo error.. and in frontend just check whether it is returning 1 or anything else.. If 1 returned then use location.href else just show the error.. If you need detail explanation then let me know. I will post an answer with a detail diagram.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question with many possible answers, but here's one way to do it.

## 1. Post your login with AJAX

```
$.post("loginScript.php", {
    username: "username goes here",
    password: "password goes here"
}, function(data){

});
```

## 2. Echo your results

Your login script should echo out a JSON response that indicates whether the login was successful and if not, what the errors were.

```
<?php

    if(//login conditions)
    {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "success"  => true
        ));
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "success"  => false,
            "errors"   => $errors
        ));
    }
```

## 3. Handle the response

```
$.post("loginScript.php", {
    username: "username goes here",
    password: "password goes here"
}, function(data){
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    if(json.success)
    {
        //Login was successful
    }
    else
    {
        var errors = json.errors;
        //Display errors on your page.
    }
});
```

Comment: all code is on one page, on the index.php , where I have the form itself, and the errors and all .. where would I place those codes then? and that case do I go .. $.post("index.php", { ?

Comment: You can post to index.php. That's fine. You'll just want to return after you echo the json out so that you don't echo out the rest of the login page HTML.

Comment: I see , do I need place any of that code in the HTML LOGIN FORM , or any where specific on my index.php?

Comment: So you would do the login check first thing in your index.php, and if successful, then echo the JSON, and if not successful, echo the error JSON, and if no POST info was sent, continue to the HTML.

Comment: I know I'm giving u a hard time now, but would u please take a look at my code above a simplify a little more to how I can place this in it ? please :)

Comment: $.post("loginScript.php", {
    username: "username goes here",
    password: "password goes here"
}, function(data){

});  .... WHERE WOULD THAT GO , I'm getting php error when it placed in my code

Comment: So instead of submitting your form the normal way, when you click the submit button, you'll want to run the `$.post` bit. So that will go in your Javascript.

Comment: so ,,, step 1 and step 3 are scripts .. they should be in <script></script> tags ?

Comment: Yes. 3 is a continuation of step 1, so #3 should be in a script tag. Put in inside a function that you call onclick of the submit button.

Comment: and how about the php code , where would that be placed on my index.php .. i get an error with itt 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\Apache24\htdocs\soon\index.php on line 247

Comment: Well the code that I posted was basically pseudocode. So just take your login code that you already have, and append the echo statements for the login success and failure. You'll want to add a submit variable to the javascript post statement too, since you check if submit is set before you try to log the user in.

Comment: damn ... a bit too confusing to me .. if someone can help me teach this according to my code posted, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: like would would hte // login condition be ? according to my code ?

Comment: `if($user->login($username,$password)){`

Comment: I think we are getting there , stay with me please .. let me figure this out, now I get ... Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\Apache24\htdocs\soon\index.php on line 249
{"success":false,"errors":"
Username required<\/span>"}   ... BUT IT IS SHOWING THE ERROR UNDER , for username required

Comment: I would suggest that you just try a basic version of this before trying to integrate it with your existing code. The code that I posted was a super basic template, so it will need some tweaking to work with the code that you posted.